# How to retain a jQuery toggle state when switching to a new page

Tags: jquery

What I would like to accomplish seems simple enough, but I have not been able to figure out how to achieve this functionality.

I have a jQuery toggle effect being applied to a navigation element called the "Quick Brew Selector." It's essentially a quick visual navigation for different beer manufacturers. Please see this in action here: http://srperrott.silverjerk.com/products/domestic/millercoors

I would like this to remain closed when you first enter into a beer page, but I feel like the transition to the next page is a bit jarring as I have some jQuery effects being applied to some elements on the page to liven up the experience. Couple this with the collapse of the Quick Brew Selector, and I feel like the experience is too jerky, or isn't smooth enough (having a hard time communicating what I find wrong with it, but I feel if the selector remains open on the next page this will resolve the problem).

I'm using a simple jQuery toggle to get the functionality I desire from the brew selector. What do I need to change in the code for the next page to load with this selector open? Here is my code thus far (I am extremely poor at jQuery, so please go easy on me!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".quick-brew-header").toggle(function(){
    $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:165},40);
    },function(){
    $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:40},40);
});
```

Comment: Have you considered the use of cookies? You could read/write the toggle state of the navigation element(s) to a cookie and then determine how to initially render it each page load by taking a peek at the cookie content. [Search for examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+toggle+state+cookie) here on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a backwards compatible solution, you could store the state in localStorage when available and in a cookie otherwise. If you don't want to use a cookie, you could append the header state in a hash fragment on each of the links in the menu, and then read the state from `document.location.href` when the next page is loaded. I wrote some code for the localStorage/cookie version below. In some ways, though, I think the hash fragment solution might be better (even though it makes your link URLs uglier), because if someone uses your beer selector and then comes back to the page an hour later, maybe you don't want to auto-expand the header at that time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function store_toggle_state(state) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      localStorage["quick-brew-header"] = state;
    } else {
      // No localStorage, so use a cookie
      // Alternatively, you could store in URL
      // $.map($(".quick-brew-container a"), function (link) {
      //    $(link).attr("href", $(link).attr("href").split("#")[0] + "#" + state;
      // });
      document.cookie = "quick-brew-header=" + state;
    }
  }

  function get_toggle_state() {
    var state = false;

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      if ("quick-brew-header" in localStorage) {
        state = localStorage["quick-brew-header"];
      }
    } else {
      // Alternatively, read state from document.location.href if it's there
      var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
      $.map($.makeArray(cookies), function (cookie_str) {
        var cookie = cookie_str.split("=");
        if (cookie[0] == "quick-brew-header") {
          state = cookie[1];
        }
      });
    }

    if (state === "true" || state === "false") {
      state = (state === "true");
    }
    return state;
  }

  function header_off() {
    store_toggle_state(false);
    $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:40},40);
  }

  function header_on() {
    store_toggle_state(true);
    $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:165}, 40);
  }

  var show_at_load = get_toggle_state();
  if (show_at_load) {
    header_on();
  } else {
    header_off();
  }
  // What happens on even/odd clicks depends on if we showed the header at page load
  $(".quick-brew-header").toggle(show_at_load ? header_off : header_on,
                                 show_at_load ? header_on : header_off);     
});
```

Comment: I think my capacity for understanding your solution is abysmally low -- I am a designer trying and failing miserably at being a front-end developer and site builder. Just implementing your code didn't get me there, but I am certain this is due to my ineptitude. I will do some further research and try and wrap my head around your solution. Thanks so much for the quick reply and the well-commented code.

Comment: I'm sorry, there were a few bugs! I had switched hiding and showing in a couple places, and forgotten to initially show or hide the menu on load. I edited the code; let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to break the Javascript on the page for me. Not sure where the problem is. Thanks for the continued assistance, Emily!

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by break the Javascript on the page? Is there a specific error you're getting?

Comment: Whenever I use the above code, all other jQuery on the page is broken. So, for instance, the Beer image never fades in, the company logo never moves down to its resting position, the toggle effect on the Quick Brew Selector becomes unresponsive. You can see this in affect here: http://srperrott.silverjerk.com/products/domestic/millercoors

Comment: Looks like an extra curly brace/paren slipped in sites/all/themes/srperrott/js/scripts.js. Try deleting line 97 (the "});") in the second to last line of that script. You might know this already, but the browser can help you spot these kinds of syntax errors; in Chrome, for example, go to Tools > Javascript console, and you will see any errors: in this case, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" and points you to the script and line in question.

Comment: Hmm, strangely, this fixes the broken code, but now the entire .zone-preface-wrapper seems to collapse and is inaccessible. Again, thanks for the patience on this, Emily. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, this is because of the line `$(".zone-preface-wrapper").toggle(show_at_load);` which actually shows or hides the target element. I suppose in this case you don't want to actually show/hide zone-preface-wrapper but instead just change the height, so you could try replacing that line with `if (show_at_load) { header_on(); } else { header_off(); }`. I edited the answer to show this.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much, Emily! I am going to delve into this code and try and wrap my head around what you've done so your hard work is not squandered!